# Motion After Rotation In Sdl C++

Tags: c++, animation, sdl

Here are my functions:

```
void main_loop(){
SDL_Surface* image;
image=SDL_LoadBMP("plane.bmp");
plane=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,image);
double angle=90;
int speed=1;
SDL_Event event;


bool quit=false;
while(!quit){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)!=0){
        if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
            quit=true;
        if(event.type==SDL_KEYDOWN){
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    angle+=90*delta;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    angle-=90*delta;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
   //update_delta();
   int angle_rad=angle*PI/180;
    x+=sin(angle_rad)*speed*delta;
    y-=cos(angle_rad)*speed*delta;
    draw((int)x,(int)y,angle);
}
last_time=SDL_GetTicks()/1000;
return;

 }

void draw(Uint32 x,Uint32 y,double angle){
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_Rect rect;
rect.x=x;
rect.y=y;
rect.h=100;
rect.w=100;
SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer,plane,NULL,&rect,angle,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Basically what I want to do is to rotate a texture, and move it a fixed speed in the direction it is facing. The delta value is the time between two frames, and i use this to figure out the increment of x and y coordinates per frame. However , there is some problem with the angles. The texture does not move properly, but at some awkward angle which makes it look like it is drifting. So far I have tried changing trig functions, negating x and y, but it simply does not work.

I am using SDL 2.0 with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int angle_rad=angle*PI/180;
```

Your radians are being stored in an integer, so they will get truncated to the nearest whole number. Store them in a float or a double instead.